# Email user that broke build in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

In Husdon/Jenkins, I can setup notifications when the build is broken to email the user(s) that made the checkins that broke the build. How do I do this in Teamcity?

I am aware that individual users can setup email notifications for themselves via the Teamcity interface (for when the build is broken), but I ONLY want emails sent to the users that broke the build, also I don't want the requirement that every individual user have to update their Teamcity settings.

Comment: which teamcity version are you using?

Comment: Teamcity 6.0 Enterprise .. seems like the only solution will be to make a custom notifer

Comment: or upgrade if you still have an active subscription. (or for free if you have less than 20 builds confs, other restrictions have fallen)

Comment: Does 6.5 support explicitly emailing the person that broke the build (irrelevant of roles/groups)?

Comment: yes it does: i think it is set up that way out of the box, but you can just set it up in group everybody, which everybody is a member of by default.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

- Open TeamCity in your browser.
- Browse to **Administration** > **Users and Groups** > **Groups**
- Click on the group name **All Users**
- Select the tab **Notification Rules** (you see the Email notifier rules by
  default)
- Click on **Add new rule**
- choose in the column **Watch** the
  option **Builds affected by my
  changes**
- choose in the column **Send
  notification when** the checkbox **The
  build fails** and **Ignore failures
  not caused by my changes**
- Save this new notification rule with klick on the **Save** button.

*A notification rule created that way works for all users. That's because the notification rule was created in the administration section within the group **All Users**, and not within one users personal notification settings. This works also in earlier versions of TeamCity, e.g. in 5.x.*

The user still has the option to define additional rules if needed.

Comment: Don't forget to check SPAM folder! I've lost one hour of my life trying to figure out where the heck are the emails from TeamCity =)

Comment: There is a way to customize the notification content if you or your SPAM-filter does not like the TeamCity defaults. Please have a look at http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Customizing+Notifications.

Comment: In TeamCity 10 I'm not seeing the option for "Builds affected by my changes" but I do see "Builds containing my changes" do you know if this is now the equivalent or has the option been removed?

Comment: It's the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

At least with Teamcity 6.5 you have roles and groups, and you can set notifications settings based on them.

To achieve what you want, just take a look at the notification for group ALL (everybody) that is configured by default and you can't delete it.

http://yourteamcityinstall/admin/editGroup.html?groupCode=ALL_USERS_GROUP&tab=groupNotifications

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is dated, and a lot of teams now use Slack. So for those of us that consider e-mail "so 2011", my team has been finding success with this nice Slack Plug-in notifier just for this purpose:

https://github.com/PeteGoo/tcSlackBuildNotifier

Simply upload the zip to the Team City plugins folder, restart the Team City server, and then configure the notifications from the Admin/Build config settings. Also, create a Slack webhook to use in the API Token field.

It can be configured to notify on a number of conditions, but we're only using the "Trigger when build fails" option currently.

Comment: And as of TeamCity 2020.1, there is out-of-box [Slack notification plugin in TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/whatsnew/#version-2020-1-level-up-your-notifications).