# How can I set up Teamcity to Email out a Release note?

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

I have a TeamCity server that builds my application and a YouTrack instance set up to track my feature requests/bugs.  I have the TeamCity/YouTrack integration setup so the Issue log correctly fills out in TeamCity with the Items that have been closed in YouTrack since the last successful build.  How can I set up TeamCity to email a user a nicely formatted email that contains this list of Issues?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180772/email-user-that-broke-build-in-teamcity

I dont know whats in the successful build email, perhaps turn it on to see what it contains

Comment: This is close, but I need to be able to include the info from YouTrack as well in the email.

Answer (score 6):

*this answer has been adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180772/email-user-that-broke-build-in-teamcity)*

- Open TeamCity in your browser.
- Browse to `Administration > User Management- Groups > All Users`
- Select the tab Notification Rules (you see the Email notifier rules by default)
- Click on Add new rule
- Select `Builds from the selected build configuration` and choose the builds you want notifications for
- On the right hand side where it says `Send notification when` tick `Build is successful`
- press `Save`

You should now get an email which has a summary of the changes, eg

> Build Compilation :: myproject #2.0. successful (Tests passed: 1288)
>
> Agent: buildagent-01
>
> Changes included: 1 change.
>
> Change 02b88b1b1345 by wturner (1 file): bug1 fixed

Comment: This gets me part of the way there.  But what I really need in addition to this is the template code to include the YouTrack work items from the 'Issues' tab of the individual build in the email.

Comment: `Issues tab of the individual build` <--where is that?

Comment: TeamCity Documentation - http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Working+with+Build+Results#WorkingwithBuildResults-RelatedIssues  p.s. if you don't have YouTrack Integration set up or you don't reference a Ticket in one of your commits in the build this tab will not show up.

Comment: I have integrations to youtrack set up but for me it is a 'Changes' tab, not an Issues tab. nonetheless, the build success email has sufficient information for each of the fixed issues. (the summary from youtrack for the issue)

Comment: The changes tab contains the source control commit messages and not the YouTrack issues that were addressed.  As a company we do not want to email our customers the commit messages as they may contain implementation details and unnecessary information for the end users.  The issues in YouTrack that were addressed however is very useful information for the end user, and is what I am looking for.

Comment: P.S. I am using TeamCity 7.0.3, what version are you using?  Maybe they have updated this in Newer versions.

Comment: im using TC 8.0.3 - i can't see this tab there is some problem but i havent figured it out yet.

Comment: FYI in 8.0.3 it is on the build configuration page but not the individual build page. As 'Issue Log'

Comment: PITaylor, did you ever figure this out or did you do something else? I am in a similar position.